# A submit preventionworks with form id but not with class

Tags: jquery, form-submit

This function works fine (#new_user is an id of a form):

```
$("#new_user").submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  return $(".terms").dialog("open");
});
```

But when i try to add a class, for example:

```
$("#new_user.team-registration").submit(function(e)
```

It doesn`t.

How can i make it work only when form#new_user also have class team-registration or artist-registration? Can be only one of them. Thanks!

Comment: I am going to take a stab: the class is dynamically added? you'll need to recollect the element after the class is added. when the dom loads `$("#new_user.team-registration")` might not be available. or use the delegate() function to bind the event handler.

Comment: Yes the class is added by another onclick function.
Could you please give an example?

Comment: Keep the handler for the ID and check for the class inside the function. There is no need to involve delegates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("#new_user").submit(function(e) {
    if(!$(this).hasClass('team-registration') && !$(this).hasClass('artist-registration')) {
        return;
    }
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.terms').dialog('open');
})
```

Answer (score 3):

Because the class has not been assigned to the form element when the line is actually processed the selector returns nothing... what you can do is use the `.delegate()` function (similar to what you would have expected .live() to do previously).  here is an example:

```
$("body").delegate("#new_user.team-registration, #new_user.artist-registration", "submit", function() {
  return false; // in jQuery this preventsDefault and stops all propagation 
});
```

Alternatively you can store the form element in a variable at the point you add the class to it then reference it thusly (this way you do not have to traverse the DOM twice)..

More can be read on .delegate() [here](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/)

Comment: If they're using jQuery 1.7 or newer they should be using `.on()` rather than `.delegate()`. Use `.delegate()` in preference of `.live()` if you're using a version older than 1.7.

Comment: Good call. ... (needed more chars)